# auto.home from AutoFS Maps from Active Directory not working

Tags: 16.04, autofs

I am trying to use auto.home which is stored on AD, but not having much luck.
I have followed https://care.qumulo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115014470007-Serving-AutoFS-Maps-from-Active-Directory-AD-to-AD-Bound-Linux-Clients-Using-SSSD#details-0-0 and I am close but something is still missing.

Summary of errors:

- key "aarbid01" not found in map source(s).
- ls: cannot access '/home/aarbid01': No such file or directory
- No sub-attributes for [objectClass]
- sdap_get_automntmap_recv failed [5]: Input/output error

The errors I am getting in full:

```
# service autofs status
autofs.service - Automounts filesystems on demand
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autofs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-03-14 16:14:45 GMT; 4min 12s ago
  Process: 6662 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9419 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/automount $OPTIONS --pid-file /var/run/autofs.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9437 (automount)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 8601)
   CGroup: /system.slice/autofs.service
           └─9437 /usr/sbin/automount --pid-file /var/run/autofs.pid

Mar 14 16:14:44 soyuz systemd[1]: Starting Automounts filesystems on demand...
Mar 14 16:14:45 soyuz systemd[1]: Started Automounts filesystems on demand.
Mar 14 16:14:48 soyuz automount[9437]: setautomntent: lookup(sss): setautomntent: No such file or directory
Mar 14 16:14:48 soyuz automount[9437]: **key "aarbid01" not found in map source(s).**
```

and

```
# ls /home/aarbid01
ls: cannot access '/home/aarbid01': No such file or directory
```

and

```
# tail  /var/log/sssd/sssd_DCS.BBK.AC.UK.log
(Mon Mar 14 16:43:56 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_parse_entry] (0x1000): OriginalDN: [CN=aarbid01,CN=auto.home,CN=dcs,CN=defaultMigrationContainer30,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC
    =ac,DC=uk].
(Mon Mar 14 16:43:56 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_parse_range] (0x2000): No sub-attributes for [objectClass]
(Mon Mar 14 16:43:56 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_parse_range] (0x2000): No sub-attributes for [nisMapName]
(Mon Mar 14 16:43:56 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_process_result] (0x2000): Trace: sh[0x563b443e48e0], connected[1], ops[0x563b443e6a70], ldap[0x563b44247f50]
(Mon Mar 14 16:43:56 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_process_message] (0x4000): Message type: [LDAP_RES_SEARCH_ENTRY]
```

and

```
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_parse_entry] (0x1000): OriginalDN: [CN=qsong01,CN=auto.home,CN=dcs,CN=defaultMigrationContainer30,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC=
ac,DC=uk].
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_parse_range] (0x2000): No sub-attributes for [objectClass]
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_parse_range] (0x2000): No sub-attributes for [nisMapName]
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_process_result] (0x2000): Trace: sh[0x563b444032d0], connected[1], ops[0x563b44405e90], ldap[0x563b44209fe0]
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_process_message] (0x4000): Message type: [LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT]
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_get_generic_op_finished] (0x0400): Search result: Success(0), no errmsg set
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_op_destructor] (0x2000): Operation 5 finished
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_get_automntmap_process] (0x0400): **Search for autofs maps, returned 2646 results**.
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_get_automntmap_process] (0x0040): **The search yielded more than one autofs map**
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_autofs_setautomntent_done] (0x0040): **sdap_get_automntmap_recv failed [5]: Input/output error**
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_id_op_done] (0x0200): communication error on cached connection, moving to next server
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_id_op_done] (0x4000): advising for connection retry #4
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_id_op_done] (0x4000): releasing operation connection
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_id_release_conn_data] (0x4000): releasing unused connection
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [sdap_handle_release] (0x2000): Trace: sh[0x563b444032d0], connected[1], ops[(nil)], ldap[0x563b44209fe0], destructor_loc
k[0], release_memory[0]
(Mon Mar 14 16:35:24 2022) [sssd[be[DCS.BBK.AC.UK]]] [remove_connection_callback] (0x4000): Successfully removed connection callback.
```

What I have:

```
# egrep autom /etc/nsswitch.conf
automount:      files sss

# egrep -v ^# /etc/auto.master
/home      auto.home
```

I have /etc/auto.home as well, but removing it does not make any difference

```
# egrep -v ^# /etc/auto.home
ahmed -fstype=nfs,vers=3 193.61.xx.xx:/staff/ahmed

# more /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

[sssd]
services = nss, pam, autofs
config_file_version = 2
domains = DCS.BBK.AC.UK
debug_level = 99


[autofs]
debug_level = 9
ldap_autofs_search_base= cn=dcs,cn=defaultMigrationContainer30,dc=dcs,dc=bbk,dc=ac,dc=uk

[domain/BBK.AC.UK]
debug_level = 9
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
ldap_id_mapping = False
override_shell = /bin/bash
# krb5_validate = false
ad_gpo_ignore_unreadable = True
# autofs
autofs_provider = ad
ldap_autofs_entry_key = cn
ldap_autofs_entry_object_class = nisObject
ldap_autofs_entry_value = nisMapEntry
ldap_autofs_map_name = nisMapName
#ldap_autofs_map_object_class = nisMap
ldap_autofs_map_object_class = nisObject
ldap_autofs_search_base= cn=dcs,cn=defaultMigrationContainer30,dc=dcs,dc=bbk,dc=ac,dc=uk
\krb5_ccname_template=FILE:%d/krb5cc_%U
```

Ldap data looks like:

```
# ldapsearch -h host.bbk.ac.uk  -b "cn=dcs,cn=defaultMigrationContainer30,dcs=dcs,dc=bbk,dc=ac,dc=uk"         -D "CN=auser,OU=MSc,OU=StudentUsers,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC=ac,DC=uk" -w password cn=ubfabo001
#

# ubfabo001, auto.home, dcs, defaultMigrationContainer30, dcs.bbk.ac.uk
dn: CN=ubfabo001,CN=auto.home,CN=dcs,CN=defaultMigrationContainer30,DC=dcs,DC=
 bbk,DC=ac,DC=uk
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisObject
cn: ubfabo001
distinguishedName: CN=ubfabo001,CN=auto.home,CN=dcs,CN=defaultMigrationContain
 er30,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC=ac,DC=uk
instanceType: 4
uSNCreated: 30884897
uSNChanged: 30884897
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE
name: ubfabo001
objectCategory: CN=NisObject,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC=ac,DC
 =uk
nisMapEntry: filesrv:/dpool/stds/itapps/itapptutors/ubfabo001
nisMapName: auto.home
msSFU30Name: ubfabo001

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

To me it looks like SSSD finds all the keys in the auto.home map but can not match them? It may be that my sssd.conf ldap_autofs_* entries do not match my AD auto.home but I can see it?

Any pointers?
Thanks
Andrew

Comment: I did not mention the entries in local /etc/auto.home all mount fine.

Comment: Sorry to say 16.04 is past EOL and not supported on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I have found the solution. It was the values of the sssd.conf

```
autofs_provider = ad
ldap_autofs_entry_key = cn 
ldap_autofs_entry_object_class = nisObject
ldap_autofs_entry_value = nisMapEntry
ldap_autofs_map_name = name 
ldap_autofs_map_object_class = container
ldap_autofs_search_base= cn=dcs,cn=defaultMigrationContainer30,dc=dcs,dc=bbk,dc=ac,dc=uk
```

To check the values you require do the following:

```
# ldapsearch -h dcsntdc03.dcs.bbk.ac.uk  -b "cn=dcs,cn=defaultMigrationContainer30,dc=dcs,dc=bbk,dc=ac,dc=uk"         -D "CN=admin,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC=ac,DC=uk" -w password  cn=auto.home objectClass name
dn: CN=auto.home,CN=dcs,CN=defaultMigrationContainer30,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC=ac,DC=uk
objectClass: top
objectClass: container    <<== ldap_autofs_map_object_class
name: auto.home           <<== ldap_autofs_map_name

# ldapsearch -h dcsntdc03.dcs.bbk.ac.uk  -b "cn=dcs,cn=defaultMigrationContainer30,dc=dcs,dc=bbk,dc=ac,dc=uk"         -D "CN=admin,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC=ac,DC=uk" -w password  cn=andrew objectClass cn name nisMapName nisMapEntry
dn: CN=andrew,CN=auto.home,CN=dcs,CN=defaultMigrationContainer30,DC=dcs,DC=bbk,DC=ac,DC=uk
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisObject  <<== ldap_autofs_entry_object_class
cn: andrew              <<== ldap_autofs_entry_key
name: andrew
nisMapName: auto.home
nisMapEntry: filesrv:/staff/andrew  <<== ldap_autofs_entry_value
```

Thanks